# Angular Unit tests failing, not able to inject servies

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

this is my karma.conf.js

```
`use strict`;

var path = require('path');
var conf = require('./gulp/conf');

var _ = require('lodash');
var wiredep = require('wiredep');

var pathSrcHtml = [
  path.join(conf.paths.src, '/**/*.html')
];

function listFiles() {
  var wiredepOptions = wiredep({
        directory: 'src/bower_components',
        exclude: [],
        dependencies: true,
        devDependencies: true
    });

  return wiredep(wiredepOptions).js
    .concat([
      path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.module.js'),
      path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.js'),
      path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/*.spec.js')
    ])
    .concat(pathSrcHtml);
}

module.exports = function(config) {
    var files=['https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'].concat(listFiles());
    var configuration = {
    files: files,

    singleRun: true,

    autoWatch: false,

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      stripPrefix: conf.paths.src ,
      moduleName: 'truelocal'
    },

    logLevel: 'WARN',

    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-filesort'],

    angularFilesort: {
      whitelist: [path.join(conf.paths.src, '/**/!(*.html|*.spec|*.mock).js')]
    },

    browsers : ['PhantomJS'],

    plugins : [
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      'karma-angular-filesort',
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor'
    ],

    coverageReporter: {
      type : 'html',
      dir : 'coverage/'
    },
    // level of logging
      // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
      logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

        captureConsole: true,
    reporters: ['progress']
  };

  // This is the default preprocessors configuration for a usage with Karma cli
  // The coverage preprocessor in added in gulp/unit-test.js only for single tests
  // It was not possible to do it there because karma doesn't let us now if we are
  // running a single test or not
  configuration.preprocessors = {};
  pathSrcHtml.forEach(function(path) {
    configuration.preprocessors[path] = ['ng-html2js'];
  });

  // This block is needed to execute Chrome on Travis
  // If you ever plan to use Chrome and Travis, you can keep it
  // If not, you can safely remove it
  // https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1144#issuecomment-53633076
  if(configuration.browsers[0] === 'Chrome' && process.env.TRAVIS) {
    configuration.customLaunchers = {
      'chrome-travis-ci': {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    };
    configuration.browsers = ['chrome-travis-ci'];
  }

  config.set(configuration);
};

//Bower.json
{
  "name": "truelocal",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.4.10",
    "angular-animate": "~1.4.10",
    "angular-aria": "~1.4.10",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.4",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.4.10",
    "angular-local-storage": "~0.2.3",
    "angular-messages": "~1.4.10",
    "angular-resource": "~1.4.10",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.4.10",
    "angular-toastr": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-touch": "~1.4.10",
    "animate.css": "~3.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
    "jquery": "~1.11.3",
    "malarkey": "yuanqing/malarkey#~1.3.1",
    "moment": "~2.10.6",
    "moment-parseformat": "~1.1.3",
    "ng-file-upload-shim": "~9.1.2",
    "jQuery.dotdotdot": "~1.7.4",
    "lodash": "3.10.1",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.18",
    "markerclustererplus": "~2.1.4",
    "ng-fastclick": "~1.0.2",
    "angular-swipe": "~0.1.0",
    "angular-bindonce": "~0.3.3",
    "angular-loading-bar": "~0.9.0",
    "jquery-placeholder": "~2.3.1",
    "angular-shims-placeholder": "^0.4.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.4.10"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot",
        "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg",
        "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf",
        "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff",
        "dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "~1.11.3",
    "angular": "^1.5.7"
  }
}
```

This is an existing project with more than 200 Unit tests written, the code might need a bit of update but i'm not able to execute any unit test with dependent services.
I'm guessing the angular-mocks is causing an issue, if i move it up in the dependencies i dont get the module missing error. but i still dont get the other dependencies in the unit tests.

Comment: I'M not able to run all the tests in one go, `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'errorService.service') in src/app/services/error.service.spec.js ` keep on getting this error for anything to be injected in the unit tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Karma.conf.js was missing one file from the project. once all the files are fed to the test conf. tests worked like a Charm!